# Update data in d3.js group

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ecmascript-6, data-driven

I create a group with data values:

```
var group = svg.append("g");
group.data([{color : "green", opacity: 0.3 }]);
```

If I want to update these values, do I need to set a new data array?

```
group.data([{color : "blue", opacity: 0.3 }]);
```

Or can I somehow iterate and update the values inside the group, like:

```
group.data.foreach(d, function() { return d.color = "blue"; })
```

or

```
group.data.foreach(d, function() { return d.opacity += 0.5; })
```

My use case is that I have a group with a rectangle and a circle. And the group has data in it.

```
var group = svg.append("g");
group.data([{color : "green", opacity: 0.3 }]);

var line = group.append("rect");
line.attr("x", self.xWorldToGraph(xx) - self.lineWidth / 2)
  .attr("y", self.yWorldToGraph(yy))
  .attr("width", self.lineWidth)
  .attr("height", height)
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return d.color; })
  .style('stroke-opacity', function(d) { return d.opacity; })

group.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", self.xWorldToGraph(xx))
  .attr("cy", self.yWorldToGraph(yy))
  .attr("r", 50)
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return d.color; })
  .style('stroke-opacity', function(d) { return d.opacity; })
```

Now I want to update the group color so the circle and rectangle also change color.

Comment: This will do group.data().foreach(d, function() { return d.color = "blue"; })

Comment: How do I tell d3 that the value in data has been updated?

Comment: I will not be able to answer that as there are many ways i think you need some insight here http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218

Comment: You "tell" `d3` the data has changed by calling the `.style` functions again.  Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/pGFoW78zM49Dxlw8Z6k2?p=preview) using @cyril `forEach`.

Comment: Thank you:) everything is working now

Comment: @Mark Do you want to add this as an answer?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, I can, it seemed like low hanging fruit for a full answer.  The problem with the enter, update, exit pattern (and closing questions about it as a duplicate) is that most people don't get it until they see it with their data in a live example.  I feel like all I do is explain it time and time again on here.

Comment: @Mark Yep, I think we've all been there :) Still it's better to answer these questions that aren't exact duplicates simply so that others will see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d3` won't "auto" redraw after you switch out data.  You have to "tell" it the data has changed by calling the .style functions again (in the enter, update, exit pattern, this is an update).

Here's an example using your code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 500)
      .attr('height', 500);

    var group = svg.append("g");
    
    group.data([{
      color: "green",
      opacity: 0.3
    }]);

    group.append("circle")
      .attr("cx", 100)
      .attr("cy", 100)
      .attr("r", 50)
      .style("stroke-width", 30)
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return d.color;
      })
      .style('stroke-opacity', function(d) {
        return d.opacity;
      });
      
    var colors = d3.scale.category20();
    var i = 0;

    function changeColor() {
      group.data().forEach(function(d) {
        d.color = colors(i);
      });
      group.selectAll('circle').style("stroke", function(d) {
        return d.color;
      })
      i++;
    }

    setInterval( changeColor, 1000 );

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```